# Change mirror of update sites of eclipse plugins

Tags: eclipse, plugins, mirror, update-site

I'm using ganymede but I can't find the option to change mirror for the update sites. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The all notion of **mirrors** is [no more a first class citizen](http://tronprog.blogspot.com/2008/07/eclipse-ganymede.html) of eclipse Ganymede update mechanism, but rather a simple property of a repositories (for [metadata or artifact](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Concepts)).

You may still force a mirror for a given feature, with a command-line similar to the one mentioned in [this bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=256909).

```
eclipsec -verbose -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication 
-source http://www.someurl.com/ -destination file:x:/local/path/to/mirror
```

(not tested though)

See also this [introduction to P2](http://bandxi.com/exposure/eclipsecon2008/359/M2-UsingEquinoxP2.pdf)

Comment: i've got totally impatient and resorted to dropins method, i'll investigate on this later. too bad there are a lot not working features in PDT in ganymede

Answer (score 0):

Just uncheck "select mirrors automatically" and it will prompt you for mirrors next time.

Comment: I dont see any "select mirrors automatically". Can you please point me  where that option is.

Comment: 'Select mirrors automatically' is a checkbox that disappears once it has been checked, and does not reappear. Amazing UI design.

Answer (score -1):

If i am not mistaken, in "Help->Software Updates" you can manage all the eclipse repositories...

Comment: I suppose you could set it to a mirror, but this doesn't bring up the Eclipse mirror dialogue